How to recover Simultaneous Output device for Sound in Ubuntu 24.04?
To play music through both the Line Out Built-in Audio and Bluetooth speakers, I implemented the answer by @DidierL that created a new “Simultaneous Output” as output device.
I then noticed a slight delay in the bluetooth speak sound. To remedy this delay, I tried the answer by @PoDuck. That is implementing
#!/bin/bash

BLUEZCARD=$(pactl list cards short | egrep -o bluez.*[[:space:]])
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD a2dp_sink
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD headset_head_unit
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD a2dp_sink

As this solution could not rectify the delay, I tried  :
#!/bin/bash

BLUEZCARD=$(pactl list cards short | egrep -o bluez.*[[:space:]])
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD off
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD a2dp_sink
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD off
pactl set-card-profile $BLUEZCARD a2dp_sink

Unfortunately, this setting broke the performance of the “Simultaneous Output” device. It does not play any sound.
Also, only the Line Out Built-in Audio works if select explicitly. When the bluetooth speaker is selected explicity, the sound is very muted.
I don't know how to undo the mess as in Ubuntu 24.04, there is not option to undo the custom Shortcut as was mentioned by @PoDuck's answer.

and then click on the right where it says Disabled to set up a keyboard shortcut to execute the script.

How do I undo the mess?
Update:
I just discovered qpwgraph. Below gives a visual of the. I notice  a few repeated modules, I wonder how it got there.

Any advice on what to do would be great.

I am a novice on setting up sound in Ubuntu. However, I found that an invaluable tool for customising the sound configuration in Ubuntu 24.04 is to use the application qpwgraph.
I noticed that whenever I change the output device on Settings -> Sound or  in pavcontrol (i.e. Volume Control) -> Playback -> Brave: Payback on, the connections can get messed up badly. This is the source of the problem.

To solve the mess, qpwgraph can be used to fix and customise the sound connections of the various devices. I just have to select the connections I want to connect and right click the mouse and select connect. Sound setting has become so much simpler with pipewire enabled in Ubuntu 24.04.

The next picture shows how I am even able to direct sound from youtube on Brave Browser to both the Built-in Audio and bluetooth speaker without even needing to use the new “Simultaneous Output” output device.

To install qpwgraph, do
sudo apt install qpwgraph 

or
sudo nala install qpwgraph

Furthermore, I read that qpwgraph can be use to configure video output too in addition to sound.
